# JavaScript For loop with square brackets

Tags: javascript

I understand the basic structure of a For loop in JavaScript.  I was looking at the following example:

```
function howMany(selectObject) {
  var numberSelected = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObject.options[i].selected) {
      numberSelected++;
    }
  }
  return numberSelected;
}
```

On the Fourth line I don't understand what you would call the 
`[i]` in terminology and why it is square brackets?

Comment: You never saw an [array](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html) ?

Comment: Get value in array at position i

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: you should also consider `selectObject` beside

Comment: `selectObject ` is an `object` having `array` property `options`. now this `array` contains `objects`, having one property `selected`

Comment: I know them as `indexer`'s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[]` is a way of selecting a property from an object given a specific `key`, in this case the key (or `index`) is `i` and the object is an `array`. In an array an index can go from 0 to the length of the array - 1.

In an object a key is the name of any property within that object. For example, you can also select the value of the property key `selected` from the object `selectObject.options[i]` by using the following: `selectedObject.options[i]['selected']`.

As an alternative to your `for loop`, you could use a `for in loop`. Which works on objects (and arrays).

```
for (var key in selectObject.options) {
    if (selectObject.options[key].selected) {
        numberSelected++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the `[i]` is used to address variables in for example an array.

Lets say you have an array names containing `sarah` and `john`. `names[0]` would return `sarah`.

What your for loop does is go over all the entries in selectObject.options and looks at the value of selected (most likely a true/false).

Answer (score 1):

selectObject.options returns an `array`, and the `[ ]`, is the way to get an element from the array, using its index (the `i` in your case)

Say you had an array of strings like so:

```
var arr = ["this", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings"];
```

and you want to access one of the array's elements, you would:

```
console.log(arr[5]); // prints "strings" to the console
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function howMany(selectObject) {
  var numberSelected = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObject.options[i].selected) {
      numberSelected++;
    }
  }
  return numberSelected;
}

In this above code why is numberSelected, and in the coditional statement numberSelected++
```